# Python - get X window ID

Tags: python, user-interface, window, xserver

I'm trying to use Python to get the X window ID of an arbitrary window.

Ideally the script would take the same form as running `xwininfo` from the shell - allowing the user to click on a window and determine the XID of the selected window.

I've had a look at the source of `xwininfo.c` (link [here](http://the-labs.com/Perl/ThePerlJournal/Issue_05_X/xwininfo.c)), but I can't find any libraries that are available for python that do the same job.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If I was trying to do this I would just use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) or [sh](http://amoffat.github.com/sh/) to run xwininfo from the shell and then grab its output and do whatever you need with it. Is there a reason you want to emulate its behavior rather than just using it?

Comment: I'm extending [Kazam screencaster](https://launchpad.net/kazam) to support recording an individual window, as well as a region or the entire desktop. To do this, it's just a case of finding the window ID as gstreamer handles the recording in the background. I don't want to run xwininfo in shell as, IMO, running programs in shell in the background isn't a particularly nice way of doing things.